# angular 4 download pdf comes out blank

Tags: c#, angular

Hello I am trying to download a pdf from a report that i create on the server. When I create it I save it on the server for a moment then I make a second call and download it.

The following is the code that is on the web API:

```
        var rootDirectory = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
        var filePath = $@"{rootDirectory}\Temp\{file}.pdf";
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        File.Delete(filePath);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content =  new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray())
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "report.pdf"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return result;
```

then I get back to the typescript and here is the code that I use do download it:

```
                this.reportsService
                    .download(id)
                    .subscribe(r => {
                        let pdf =r._body;
                        var pdfName = `${this.selectedReport.name}.pdf`;
                        let blob = new Blob([pdf], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                    });

            });
```

I should mention that when I open the pdf from where it is saved on the server it is correct.
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the value of `r._body` when debugging?

Comment: it looks like the bytes that were downloaded.

Comment: does anyone know?